# Java Decimal format wrong output

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I am trying to print out a specific decimal format for a double and it doesn't print out the way I want it to print. For example, instead of printing 26.40, it prints 26,40. Can someone help me please? 
Thank you in advance :) 
Here is my code:

```
DecimalFormat decimal= new DecimalFormat("#.00");

/* The following public method returns the estimated price of the CPU based on the supplied sQuarterYear variable*/
public double priceNow(String sQuarterYear){
    double estimatedPrice = 0;
    decimal.format(estimatedPrice);
    int launch_year = Integer.parseInt(this.launch_date.substring(this.launch_date.length()-2)); // Initial launch Year
    int launch_quarter = Integer.parseInt(this.launch_date.substring(1,this.launch_date.length()-3)); // Initial launch Quarter
    int launch_year2 = Integer.parseInt(sQuarterYear.substring(sQuarterYear.length()-2)); // Supplied launch Year
    int launch_quarter2 = Integer.parseInt(sQuarterYear.substring(1,sQuarterYear.length()-3)); // Supplied launch Quarter
    int uncount_quarter = 4-launch_quarter2; // Quarter that are not counted
    int count_year = 0;

    for (int i = launch_year; i <= launch_year2; i++){
        count_year++;
    }       
    int total_quarter = ((4*count_year) - launch_quarter - uncount_quarter);

    /* Here, the supplied launch year and launch quarter will be compared and if the supplied QuarterYear is after the launch
     * date (the supplied launch quarter and launch year are higher than the initial launch quarter and year, then it will calculate
     * the depreciation */
    if(launch_quarter2 >= launch_quarter && launch_year2>= launch_year){
        estimatedPrice = suggprice - suggprice*total_quarter*0.02;
    }
    else
        return estimatedPrice; /* If the supplied QuarterYear is before the launch date, there will be no depreciation and therefore will return the suggested price */
    if (estimatedPrice < 0.0) // If the estimated price is lower than 0.0, then it will return the suggested price
        return suggprice;
    else
        return estimatedPrice; /* Otherwise, it will calculate the estimated price and return it*/
}
/*The toString method to return all the values of a CPU object*/
public String toString(){
    return "This CPU is " + this.generation + "th generation " + this.series.toString() + " (" + this.speed + "GHz), launched: " + this.launch_date.toString() + " with price: " + decimal.format(this.suggprice) + " USD. SGX is " + this.sgx_support.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: Is your system locale French?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Or German, Italian, Spanish, Swedish, and many other languages.

Comment: @Andreas I took a *wild guess*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am not sure, I think it is french... When you say "System locale", do you mean the language of my computer?

Comment: @Jennifer Oui. The "," is the decimal separator in that (and as Andreas pointed out several other) language(s).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, so how do I change it? Do I have to change the language of my computer?

Comment: @Jennifer With Andreas posted solution. In what way does it not work?

Comment: No, I tried and it didn't

Comment: OMG, never mind, it worked, it because I didn't put it in the right place, thank you very much ElliottFrisch & @Andreas for your help :) It is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want American formatting, you have to say so:

```java
DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
```

Comment: It didn't work... I added: import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols; and import java.util.Locale, and it didn't work